# Use Kotlin coroutines to make multiple webservice calls simultaneously

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I tried reading the docs, but it just doesn't make sense to me.

I need to make three calls to an external webserivce and log the result of each after it returns. Each webservice call is *in*depdentant of the responses of the others. Done synchronously, it looks like this:

```
fun makeWebserviceCalls(){
    callOne()
    callTwo()
    callThree()
}

fun callOne(){
    // make webservice call
    // log result
}

fun callTwo(){
    // make webservice call
    // log result
}

fun callThree(){
    // make webservice call
    // log result
}
```

Now I just need to do that in parallel. It shouldn't be that hard, but it's just not making sense to me.

I've tried:

```
fun makeWebserviceCalls(){
    callOne()
    callTwo()
    callThree()
}

fun callOne(){
    launch{
        // make webservice call
        // log result
    }
}
```

but that doesn't compile.

I've tried:

```
fun makeWebserviceCalls(){
    runBlocking{
        callOne()
        callTwo()
        callThree()
    }

}

suspend fun callOne(){
    launch{
        // make webservice call
        // log result
    }
}
```

but that doesn't compile.

I've tried:

```
fun makeWebserviceCalls(){
    runBlocking{
        callOne()
        callTwo()
        callThree()
    }

}

suspend fun callOne(){
    withContext(Dispatchers.IO){
        // make webservice call
        // log result
    }
}
```

but this can't be right, because withContext is used when you need a result returned, which I don't.

What's the right way to do what I'm trying to do?

Comment: Don’t do something because you’ve heard “it’s better”. Why can’t you just use threads, unless you’ve a bottleneck that needs to be solved using Coroutines? Clearly, you don’t understand Coroutines, so even if you got it working, what about maintainability?

Comment: I *could* use threads.

But why would I do something the old way when there's a newer, faster, better way? I'm just trying to learn & use best practices.

Comment: There’s that word, “newer”. “Faster” and “better” are use case dependent. If you’re learning, that’s great, learn before you apply it at work on a production codebase.

Comment: That's what I'm trying to do. 

Comment: Coroutines are not completely trivial to learn. You won’t be able to learn proper use by trial and error like this. You need to read through the official documentation on them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The primary goal of Coroutines is to do efficient asynchronous operations, which is different than doing concurrent operations. Here’s an example from the official docs:

```
val client = HttpClient()
//Running in the main thread, start a `get` call
client.get<String>("https://example.com/some/rest/call")
//The get call will suspend and let other work happen in the main thread, and resume when the get call completes
```

All of the above happen on the main thread, no separate threads are spawned. A future versions of Coroutines will provide OOTB support for concurrent Coroutines on multiple threads, but the main branch has no support for that yet.

A `suspend` function can be executed on a different thread:

```
suspend fun differentThread() = withContext(Dispatchers.Default){
    println("Different thread")
}
```

Of course, if you call the `suspend` function from a regular function, you’ll need to do it within `runBlocking`.

Other alternatives are proposed here: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/mobile/concurrency-and-coroutines.html#alternatives-to-kotlinx-coroutines. For simple use cases, [CoroutineWorker](https://github.com/Autodesk/coroutineworker) is a good option.

For more details, see the official docs: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/mobile/concurrency-and-coroutines.html

Comment: You were right; I should just use threads. It just took me a little bit to recognize that. Thanks for the correction!

Answer (score -1):

If you need your `makeWebserviceCalls()` to wait until all requests to finish:

```
runBlocking(Dispatchers.IO) {
    launch { callOne() }
    launch { callTwo() }
    launch { callThree() }
}
```

If you need to start them in the background and return immediately:

```
GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
    launch { callOne() }
    launch { callTwo() }
    launch { callThree() }
}
```

But you need to understand that this is not the usual way of using coroutines. Normally, your `makeWebserviceCalls()` function and all call* functions would be `suspend` functions which makes them more coroutines-friendly.

You start parallel execution from out of the coroutines context, also parallel blocks of code are blocking and in such a case I'm not sure if it makes sense to use coroutines at all. You can just start 3 background threads, it will be effectively almost the same.

Comment: Sorry, I oversimplified my example. My actual app is making like 30 external webservice calls, and I read that creating 30 coroutines is generally better than creating 30 threads.

If I make all of my `call*` functions suspend, that would simply mean that I'm required to call them from within a coroutine, correct? Because that's what I'm doing anyway.

I plan to keep my `makeWebserviceCalls` non-suspend, because it's not being called from a coroutine.

It's a Spring project btw.

Thanks for the info!

Comment: [The reason to avoid GlobalScope](https://elizarov.medium.com/the-reason-to-avoid-globalscope-835337445abc)

Comment: Generally it is better to start 30 coroutines than 30 threads, but if these coroutines does never really suspend and only block the thread, then coroutines framework internally will just start 30 threads anyway. There may be some small advantages in using coroutines here, for example we reuse threads (but we get the same using any thread pool), also with `runBlocking()` we can easily fail with exception if any request fails, but if you just need to run some request in the background and outside of coroutines context, then you won't get too much from using them.